# Exchange Managed API: How do I search all appointments that have been created since a defined date?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Using Exchange Managed ApI, I need to get all appointments that have a created date that is newer or equal to a defined date. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the FindItems request to do this:

```
var items = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeCreated, DateTime.Today), new ItemView(100));
```

Note that you won't get recurring-appointment expansion, so only the master appointments of a recurring appointment is returned.

Comment: Sadly, no. The FindAppointments method on the ExchangeService has no overload to provider a SearchFilter. You have to filter on the client.